Formula for text cells and summarised those cells with a financial value
I'm searching for a formula in Excel that can count each cell from J6:T6 that has a text in it. Summarise this with a value of €12.50 for each cell and put that in cell U6.
So.. if J6 has a text value in it then U6 has a value of €12.50.
If cells J6 and J7 has a text then U6 is €25.00
When more cells in the range from J6:T6 has a text in it, then for each cell summarise it by the value of €12.50.
If al the cells J6:T6 have a text in it, the total is €137.50 (11x€12.50)
Is this possible in Excel?
Thanks for reading and if possible, for your help!!
Greetings from the Netherlands

What have you tried so far to answer your question? Do you want to count a cell if it has a number in it or only if it has text in it? Sharing example data would be helpful.

Describing data is never as clear as you think it may be. Consider providing sample data in the form of a markdown table

The question is not precise, because Excel distinguishes between data types, including numbers and text.
So are you talking only about cells with text content, or cells containing any content?
In the first case, you can use the formula:
=SUM(ISTEXT(J6:T6)*12.5)

And in the second:
=COUNTA(J6:T6)*12.5

The easiest way to enter a currency is to apply a currency format to the cell.


Just checked these formula's you send me and both solutions works.
Thanks for your Help!
